# Docker Swarm with TLS: Compose behaves strangely using DOCKER_CERT_PATH

Tags: ssl, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have two machines (Ubuntu Server 16.04) running a Docker Swarm cluster. On each machine runs:

- Docker 1.11.2
- Consul 0.6.4
- Docker Swarm Manager and Node swarm/1.2.3
- Docker Compose 1.7.1

Everything is encrypted with TLS.

I followed the instructions on https://docs.docker.com/swarm/configure-tls/#/step-9-configure-the-engine-cli-to-use-tls and added a `.bash_profile` inside my home directory:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://10.0.0.38:4000
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

After `source .bash_profile` the `docker ps` command runs without problems:

```
manager@master:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
9a609e5f2688        gliderlabs/registrator   "/bin/registrator -in"   17 hours ago        Up 57 minutes                                  slave1/master_registrator_1
228a225e8659        registry:2               "/bin/registry serve "   18 hours ago        Up 46 minutes       10.0.0.38:5000->5000/tcp   master/master_registry_1
```

But when I try `docker-compose ps` it throws the following error:

```
manager@master:~$ docker-compose ps
ERROR: SSL error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)
```

The Swarm Manager complains about missing ca:

> http: TLS handshake error from 10.0.0.38:52104: remote error: unknown
>   certificate authority

But when I define the certs as arguments everything seems to work (with some warnings though):

```
manager@master:~$ docker-compose --tlscert /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cert.pem --tlskey /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/key.pem ps
/tmp/_MEIgsthqj/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:768: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
/tmp/_MEIgsthqj/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:768: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
Name   Command   State   Ports 
------------------------------
```

I did not defined the ca.pem but it seems that compose cannot find the right certs without the arguments.

Here is the directory containing the certs:

```
manager@master:~$ ls -l /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 master master 1180 Jul 13 09:19 ca.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 master master 1107 Jul 13 10:08 cert.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 master master 1675 Jul 13 10:07 key.pem
```

What do I miss? The certs seem fine, because they work with docker itself and docker-compose with arguments.

Exact versions:

Docker

```
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 22:00:43 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 22:00:43 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Swarm

```
Server:
 Version:      swarm/1.2.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   eaa53c7
 Built:        Fri May 27 17:25:03 UTC 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Compose

```
docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 0a9ab35
docker-py version: 1.8.1
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

**Update**

After some research (https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3365) it seems that the env vars `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` and `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` effects the docker-compose command. So I tried to access the Docker Swarm Manager directly via curl and *without* the env vars set:

```
curl --cert $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/cert.pem --key $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/key.pem https://10.0.0.38:4000/networks
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

But after adding these lines into my `.bash_profile` and after `source .bash_profile`:

```
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.pem
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.pem
```

the requests work:

```
curl --cert $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/cert.pem --key $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/key.pem https://10.0.0.38:4000/networks
[{"Name":"slave1/bridge","Id"...
```

Sadly the error on `docker-compose` stays (even with arguments):

```
manager@master:~$ docker-compose --tlscert /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cert.pem --tlskey /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/key.pem ps
ERROR: SSL error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)
```